# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' How to get occurence from data list

Tags: python

I have a list like this :

```
  list A = [['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['Proemine
nceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS']['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS']
    , ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCR
S'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RasterPCRS'], ['SeuilPCRS']]
```

How can I found occurence and get a new list with only `[ProeminenceBatiPCRS, RailPCRS]` ? 
I tried this but I have always same error :

```
 data = set(listA)
 print(data)
```

ERROR :

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is an ordered structure (items within the list are in an order), whereas `set` is unordered. So you can do `my_list[1]`, but not `my_set[1]`. The problem is, you basically have a list of strings, but each string is also in a separate list. Those internal lists can't be added to a set. So you need to de-embed your strings from their own lists, like this:

```
list_A = [['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'],['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS']]
unwrapped_list = [internal_list[0] for internal_list in list_A]
set_A = set(unwrapped_list)

>>> print(list_A)
>>> print(unwrapped_list)
>>> print(set_A)
[['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['ProeminenceBatiPCRS'], ['RailPCRS'], ['RailPCRS']]
['ProeminenceBatiPCRS', 'ProeminenceBatiPCRS', 'RailPCRS', 'RailPCRS']    
{'RailPCRS', 'ProeminenceBatiPCRS'}
```

And if you really want the unique words in a list at the end instead of a set, add this at the end:

```
unique_list = list(set_A)
>>> print(unique_list)
['RailPCRS', 'ProeminenceBatiPCRS']
```

Note that if your internal lists ever have more than 1 string in them you will need to adjust this code, which just grabs the 1st string from each internal list.

Answer (score 1):

A list is a mutable object, so it is unhashable. If you want to create a set, then you can convert your lists to tuples:

```
set(map(lambda x: tuple(x), listA))

>>> {('ProeminenceBatiPCRS',),
    ('ProeminenceBatiPCRS', 'RailPCRS'),
    ('RailPCRS',),
    ('RasterPCRS',),
    ('SeuilPCRS',)}
```